# Is there a way in Excel to filter out duplicates even if the items occur in a different order within cells? (VBA solutions are also welcome)

Tags: vba, excel

What I am trying to do is some sort of smart "remove duplicates" in Excel.

I have a list of 200+ cells and each cell in the list potentially contains multiple items separated by a semi-colon (;).So, imagine I have a cell containing items (a,f,g) and another cell containing items (g,a,f). 
Those cells are duplicates since they contain exactly the same items, but in a different order. However the order has no importance to me.

Is there a way that excel could recognize such cells as duplicates?

Many thanks in advance for you suggestions :)

Comment: Of course there is a way.  What have you tried?

Comment: I would use a `Scripting.Dictionary` to check for duplicates. You'll have to iterate over all the cells and use  `Split(Cells(x,y).Value, ";" )` to split the values into an Array.  Next you loop through the values of the Array testing to see if the value `Exists` in the `Scripting.Dictionary`.  If it does then remove the value from the cell else `Add` the new Key to the `Scripting.Dictionary`.

Comment: I would really like to upvote the question but without an example of attempted code,  it should be closed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ThomasInzina. I hadn't tried anything for the time being because I was not even sure whether this was possible. I was hoping of getting inspired here :)

Comment: I understand but that is not how SO works.

Comment: If you can provide some Sample data and code  that will iterate over range, I will be glad to post an answer.

Comment: @ThomasInzina I do not have any sample code. I do have Sample data, but I did not post it because my problem is as simple as described in the question and I did not want to make the question too heavy. Apologies for misusing SO if this is the case. However, I had seen questions in the past in which people simple wonder if an action was even possible in Excel and I though this was also the purpose of SO :)

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one column, the solution is simple.

1. Use split to columns using ";" as delimiter
2. Sort the row, please note you have to sort row wise not column
3. Concatenate
4. use the highlight duplicate option.

In my opinion, this should be less time taking than going VBA way

Comment: what if I have more than  one column? What I have is a matrix. And I would like to remove duplicates in the first column (which represent the row "headers"). In the other column are values (say 1,0) which I would like to keep if the row headers is not a duplicate. Many thanks

Comment: Are you worried about overwriting the data in case you split?

Comment: Yes and also I was struggling in filtering all the rows at once since in the option "filter left to right" we have to select row by row. But I imagine I can write a macro for that. Overwriting data in the table is indeed my main concern

Comment: To sort you can use a macro, that'll be good. In order to avoid overwriting, copy the column , paste it into other sheet, perform steps 1,2&3 from the answer and once you've concatenated, paste it back to the original sheet. Then use the column to remove duplicates.